# How do I turn item ordering HQL into a filter query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, filtering

I have this query:

```
sess.createQuery("from Box b join b.items bi order by bi.name").list()
```

It works fine.
However, I have a hibernate's Collection boxes and want to filter is.
Naive tries:

```
 sess.createFilter(boxes, "join this.items bi order by bi.name").list()
 sess.createFilter(boxes, "from this join this.items bi order by bi.name").list()
```

don't work!

What's the proper way to convert this HQL to filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
session.createFilter(items.getBoxes(), "order by this.name").list()
```

Comment: Hehe, I feel so dumb like those teenagers on yahoo answers featured on failblog.

Answer (score 0):

When writing [collection filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-filtering), `this` refers to collection **element**.

You can write something like:

```
sess.createFilter(boxes, "where this.name = ?").list();
```

That said, I don't see any conditions in your example. I'm not sure whether `order by` is allowed in collection filters (haven't tried it), but if all you want to do is sort collection elements you can specify sort order via [@OrderBy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections) annotation:

```
@OrderBy("name")
private List items;
```

Comment: No I can't write something like this, because I can't introduce a join that easily. What you really mean is "order by this.items.name", but it won't work.

And no, I can't specify sort order via @OrderBy, because it's an order, not the order: it's different each time.

And you can use order by in filters.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. So you're trying to order a collection by a property of its own collection element - that won't work as part of the filter. To be honest, I'm not quite sure why it would even make sense - if one "box" has items A and B and the other A and C the resulting ordering will be random.

Comment: I've rewrote this query to still be a query, it's ugly but it does work.
The question of sense is the another question.